# Из консоли запуск php скрипта с подключенным контейнером php

Tags: php, docker, apache2

Подскажите пожалуйста

Цель - менять окружение(php версию и только) для php скриптов старого проекта

Запуск скриптов - будет производится по крону или из консоли или через Apache

Выбор метода - выбор пал на docker, потому что ubuntu последней версии уже не поддерживает php ниже 5.6, а проект старый

Пока что научился запускать версию php из контейнера

```
 docker run -t -i php:5.4 /bin/bash
    root@c92c6b9786e5:/# php -i
    phpinfo()
    PHP Version => 5.4.45
```

Вопрос - как мне запустить контейнер(-d) чтобы могли работать php скрипты по крону, или открыв n количество консолей можно было использовать php ???

Ведь по факту работает демон контейнера с php, а на сервере php не установлен

Comment: Так а что мешает собрать из исходников нужной версии PHP и запустить явно указав путь к бинарнику консольному?

Comment: явно указав путь к бинарнику консольному? @Ninazu как это делается?

Answer (score 1):

Проверил только что на версии LinuxMint19 (Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic) php5.3 замечательно работает

Старые версии можно брать отсюда http://php.net/releases/

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libxml2-dev pkg-config
wget http://pl.php.net/get/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror -O php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
tar jxf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.29
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.3.29 --with-config-file-path=/opt/php-5.3.29
make
sudo make install
```

Ну и проверить версию можно так

```
/opt/php-5.3.29/bin/php -v
```

Comment: после этого добавил sudo ln -f -s /opt/php-5.3.29/bin/php /etc/alternatives/php